# Adding a check issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to check if only the specific user has typed `yes` or `no` then apply the role.

At the moment if a mentionable role is added it will first return a message asking the user whether they want to add this role. However this line causes a conflict say when another user types yes it it applies the original user the role.

This is not the result I expected. So how would I go about adding a check?

Here is the code I'm working with and the line where I'm having the issue.

```
  if msg is None or msg.content.lower().strip() in ("yes", "y"):
            await author.add_roles(role)
            message = '{} added the role **{}**.'.format(author.display_name, role.name)
            embed = discord.Embed(description=message.format(author.display_name, role.name), colour=0x56e011)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(description='Okay I won\'t add the role **{}**.'.format(role.name))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

The full code:

```
async def add(self, ctx, *, rolename):
    author = ctx.message.author
    role_dict = {
        "blue":556228119565041726,
        "green":556228124719710261,
        "orange":556228127567904790,
        "yellow":556228225320222757}
    role_id = role_dict.get(rolename.lower())
    if not role_id:
        message = 'I cannot find the role **{}**.'
        embed = discord.Embed(description=message.format(rolename))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id = role_id)
    if role in author.roles:
        message = 'It looks like you already have the role **{}**.'
        embed = discord.Embed(description=message.format(role.name))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    if role.mentionable:
        message = '**@mention** notifications are enabled for the role **{}**. If you still want to add this role type **Yes** otherwise **No**.'.format(role.name)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=message.format(author.display_name, role.name), colour=0xff8100)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", timeout=20.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('Sorry, you took too long. Try again.')
            return 

        if msg is None or msg.content.lower().strip() in ("yes", "y"):
            await author.add_roles(role)
            message = '{} added the role **{}**.'.format(author.display_name, role.name)
            embed = discord.Embed(description=message.format(author.display_name, role.name), colour=0x56e011)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(description='Okay I won\'t add the role **{}**.'.format(role.name))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
    else:
        await author.add_roles(role)
        message = '{} added the role **{}**.'.format(author.display_name, role.name)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=message.format(author.display_name, role.name), colour=0x56e011)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code I use to produce check functions for `wait_for`.  Below is what I use for waiting for messages

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

def make_sequence(seq):
    if seq is None:
        return ()
    if isinstance(seq, Sequence) and not isinstance(seq, str):
        return seq
    else:
        return (seq,)

def message_check(channel=None, author=None, content=None, ignore_bot=True, lower=True):
    channel = make_sequence(channel)
    author = make_sequence(author)
    content = make_sequence(content)
    if lower:
        content = tuple(c.lower() for c in content)
    def check(message):
        if ignore_bot and message.author.bot:
            return False
        if channel and message.channel not in channel:
            return False
        if author and message.author not in author:
            return False
        actual_content = message.content.lower() if lower else message.content
        if content and actual_content not in content:
            return False
        return True
    return check
```

You can then easily pass the requirements of the message you want to receive to `wait_for`

```
check = message_check(author=ctx.author, channel=ctx.channel, content=('y', 'yes'))
msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", timeout=20.0, check=check)
```

Comment: This is good but this is the issue I'm getting here is `content = tuple(c.lower() for c in content)` `AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Here is how I'm trying your code:

https://hatebin.com/nstphesufq

Comment: @James I had a typo, the line above should be `content = make_sequence(content)`