# How do I reliably get user input as a variable from a list of certain options using discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a guessing game in a Discord bot. I have the game done, but not sure how to retrieve user input via Discord.
I know about that wait_for method to get a specific response. The problem is that it checks only for specific strings. I am looking for way to check for a list of possible strings and store whichever one it checks true for. (EX: If one of the strings is used as the it stores that input to a variable)

```py
possible_numbers = [i for i in range(1,51)]
def check(m):
    if m.content in possible_numbers:
        return m.content == m.content and m.channel == channel
guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=120.0)
```

I am expecting for something along these lines to successfully check if m.content is in possible_numbers, and if so just retrieve m.content and store it as "guess". 
Currently it just outs puts nothing and if I change it to:

```py
def check(m):
    return m.content == '1' and m.channel == channel
guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=120.0)
```

It will only accept whatever is the direct string it checks for.

Comment: May I ask why you return `m.content == m.content`? Should always be true

Comment: Here's the code I use, it checks for multiple channels/authors/messages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811719/adding-a-check-issue/55812442#55812442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`possible_numbers = [str(i) for i in range(1,51)]`

You can't compare an `int` to a `string` with `==`. So, make the list contain only strings.

Comment: Alright thanks that did fix the issue with it responding to any numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps have a method that will interpret the entire message they post to trigger the command?

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx): # compute every message, not just commands
    message_being_interpreted = ctx.content.lower()
    print(message_being_interpreted ) # will print all messages
    # do things to parse it like this
    if "!guess" in message_being_interpreted:
        pass # or do stuff
```

This would work great if the user is supposed to supply the argument with their command like `!guess 17463`, but you could also make it so users just have to type a guess like `17463`, and then when they input the correct guess it triggers some event.